# Ubuntu Server Double Accounting For Space Used

Tags: server, mount, disk-usage

All - I have installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 and mounted an LVM drive under /media.

It seems though that the server is double accounting for space and reporting that / has run out of space.

Is there any way to tell Ubuntu not to do this so that reporting is more realistic as I believe it is stopping Plex starting now.

> 32M   /etc 
>   13M   /home
>   4.0K  /tmp
>   4.0K  /mnt 
>   374M  /lib
>   9.3M  /bin
>   4.0K  /dev 12M    /sbin 56K   /root
>   4.3G  /var 16K    /lost+found
>   **1.2T    /media**
>   4.0K  /srv 
>   99M   /opt 
>   0 /sys
>   2.1G  /usr 
>   62M   /boot
>   **1.2T    /**
>
> System information as of Sat Jan  3 19:50:54 GMT 2015
>
> System load:  1.96                Processes:             152
>   **Usage of /:   100.0% of 68.63GB**   Users logged in:       1   Memory usage: 11%                 IP address for eth0:      Swap
>   usage:   0%                  IP address for virbr0:
>
> => / is using 100.0% of 68.63GB